# Ideal architecture for ML training -> API service workflow, with multiple models/services?

Tags: python, rest, machine-learning, aws

I'm planning to construct a workflow/environment for training and serving NLP classifiers, that follows something like:

1. The model training system takes in annotated documents from a subset of a variety of preconfigured sources, along with a set of user-defined parameters on how to run the model (e.g. which n-gram features to generate, whether to apply negation/lemmatization, etc)
2. Model training system outputs a model file to an S3 bucket
3. A Flask-based API service loads the model from S3 on startup, and uses it to provide real-time prediction

However, there are a few caveats:

- The training workflow will feed into multiple stand-alone services, not just one
- Each service might have multiple models attached to it (so an incoming POST of a document would receive a response with multiple classifications, based on multiple different model predictions)
- The calls per minute per service would be relatively low (maybe one call to a service every few minutes)

---

I've looked into existing offerings like SageMaker, but that's limited to one API service per model. It's also seemingly designed for API services that would [receive thousands of calls per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422065/aws-sagemaker-hosting-multiple-models-on-the-same-machine-ml-compute-instance), which is not at all cost-effective for my needs.

---

As such, here's my plan:

**Pre-/Post-processing Package**. Have a code repo containing all the pre- or post-processing methods that might be called by the classifier pipeline (both in training and in prediction). These methods all include a high amount of logic variance, dictated by input params. This code is, on its own, not deployed anywhere.

**Training service**. A high-resource EC2 instance which imports the above pre-/post-processing package, has input connectors to all possible data sources, and outputs to an S3 bucket. Data scientists would input a set of params and data source(s) and run the training on this instance.

**Model storage**. Outputted models are stored in various S3 buckets, based on some organizational structure related to the data sources and classifier type.

**API services**. A series of low-resource Flask-based API services which use config files to dictate which models to load from the S3 bucket. This *also* would need to import the pre-/post-processing package, so it could apply said methods during prediction of incoming docs.

---

So, my questions:

**Does this general architecture make sense? Or are there sections I should rethink?**

**Are there existing cost-effective systems I should be looking into which would handle this better than constructing the entire ecosystem myself?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider Amazon Sagemaker, wihch is designed for exactly for this usecase. It can be combined with Amazon Glue (only python2.7 at the moment).

Comment: SageMaker definitely seems like a useful in general, but as I mentioned in my original post, it doesn't really fit my use case. For one, as far as I can tell, it does not support multiple models served by a single service. But also, it seems designed (and priced) for scaling to high numbers of predictions per second, which I don't need - meaning it would not be a particularly cost-effective solution for my system.